# How to change the location of the default installation package for julia (1.8.5)?

Tags: julia

How to change the location of the default installation package for julia (1.8.5)? I don't want to install the package to the c drive, because both pwd () and homedir () default to the c drive, how to modify them? I want to open Julia every time like installing python packages, there is a fixed installation path (eg user_Base, User_site).

I hope there is an accurate procedure to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Julia binaries you can unpack the tar.gz to any folder (or download the portable version in case of Windows).

For the Julia packages there is one system variable that controls everything.
It is named `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH.`

In case of Windows you could set it to something like:

```
JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=d:\my_julia_depo_folder
```

In Windows you just right Click "This PC" in explorer, select "Advanced system settings" and then "Environment variables". Set JULIA_DEPOT_PATH as above and you are good to go.

Note that Julia needs to be started so it "sees" the new variable.
In Julia console you can run `versioninfo()` to see if all went right.