# How to configure Julia to install packages to a different folder on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, julia

I want to install Julia 1.9.2 on a laptop which has little space in the `C` drive so I want all packages to be installed on a `D` drive.

However, Julia installs everything to `C:\Users\MyUserName\.julia`

How to instruct it to install packages to `D:\Juliaenv` instead?

I tried advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398629/change-package-directory-in-julia) and from [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/669), as well as other forums in the internet (most are outdated and don't work with julia 1.9), tried to set environmental variables like `JULIA_PKGDIR` - nothing works.

Comment: Maybe see: [How to change the location of the default installation package for julia (1.8.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072461)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment set the Windows environment variable:

```
mkdir D:\Juliaenv\Julia1.9.2
set JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=D:\Juliaenv\Julia1.9.2
```

This will last for a single command line session.
For a permanent change go to "Advanced System Settings" in Windows and edit system variables accordingly.